# ^\sharp with slanted italic font

Tags: mathspec, italic-correction

With certain fonts with strongly slanted italics are used in math mode, `$f^\sharp$` collides the `f` and the `\sharp`. Is there a good way to deal with this, except for adding some kind of manual italic correction?

Comment: The manual explains this on pages 9-11: $"f^{\sharp}$ should be OK.

Comment: @egreg: which manual?

Comment: The manual of mathspec that's cited in the tag.

Comment: strongly slanted italics aren't really appropriate for math.  this problem more often happens with script fonts, which are almost always too strongly sloped.  good math fonts are hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

As egreg said, "`$f^{\sharp}$` seems to do the trick, though some further adjustment may be needed."